# Creating a new dataframe from existing ones based on logical not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I believe that my problem is really straightforward and there must be an really easy way to solve this issue, however as I am quite new with Python, I could not sort it out by my own an elegant solution. This question is very likely duplicated, however I could not find it, so please, if you have seen another question to my problem, take this as another way to elaborate on it.

So, let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Column A': [300,300,450,500,500,750,600,300,800],
'Column B': [1,1,2,2,3,3,0,2,3], 
'Column C': ["Value_1", "Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4", "Value_1", 
"Value_2", "Value_3", "Value_4", "Value_5"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column A','Column B', 'Column C'])
```

From there, I take two other dataframes:

```
df1 = df.loc[(df['Column C'] == "Value_4")]

df2 = df.loc[(df['Column C'] == "Value_3")]
```

Now I want to create a third dataframe (df3) which is composed by the rows present in df (existing dataframe) that ARE NOT in df1 and df2. I don't want to extract or change anything on the existing dataframe (df).

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) with 
[`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) and select rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df3 = df.loc[df.index.difference(df1.index.union(df2.index))]
print (df3)
   Column A  Column B Column C
0       300         1  Value_1
1       300         1  Value_2
4       500         3  Value_1
5       750         3  Value_2
8       800         3  Value_5
```

Another idea is use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with both value used for filtering and invert condition by `~`:

```
df3 = df[~df['Column C'].isin(['Value_4','Value_3'])]
```

Or if need test all columns by values for membership is possible use `indicator=True` in `merge` with `concat`ed both DataFrames:

```
s = df.merge(pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(), how='left', indicator=True)['_merge']

df3 = df[s == 'left_only']
print (df3)
   Column A  Column B Column C
0       300         1  Value_1
1       300         1  Value_2
4       500         3  Value_1
5       750         3  Value_2
8       800         3  Value_5
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple way to do this is:

1. first you have to set your column name with no space.

---

2. you have to get `unique` values of `Column_C` for `df1` and `df2` and create `list`.

   ```
   l=[df1['Column_C'].unique()[0],df2['Column_C'].unique()[0]]
   ```

---

3. then use NOT IN with df.

   ```
   df3 = df[~df.Column_C.isin(l)]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove index of df2+df3 from df.index and use the diff to reindex df:

```
df.reindex(df.index.difference(df1.index.union(df2.index)))

    Column A    Column B    Column C
0   300         1           Value_1
1   300         1           Value_2
4   500         3           Value_1
5   750         3           Value_2
8   800         3           Value_5
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, may be you can do this by using [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and negating it using `~` (there are many ways to get to your solution, I post one of them):

```
df3 = df.loc[~(df['Column C'].isin(df1['Column C'])) & ~(df['Column C'].isin(df2['Column C']))]
```

What we do is, we check for rows from df which are not in df1 for Column C, the same for df and df2 with Column C. You are left with other rows then as shown below.

Output:

```
   Column A  Column B Column C
0       300         1  Value_1
1       300         1  Value_2
4       500         3  Value_1
5       750         3  Value_2
8       800         3  Value_5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df3 = df.loc[~(df['Column C'] == "Value_4") & ~(df['Column C'] == "Value_3")]
```